# calculating sum of items in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get input from the user and put it into a list then calculate the total but I keep getting an error "not iterable"
there is the code:

```
def sales_function():
    month_list = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
    month_sale = []
    for months in month_list :
        user_input = int(input(print("Enter the sales for " + months +":" )))
        month_sale.append(user_input)
    for items in range(len(month_sale)):
        total_sales = sum(items)
        print("Total sales:" + total_sales)
```

sales_function()

Comment: `items` is a list index, a single number like `0` or `1`. The argument to `sum()` needs to be a sequence of numbers that can be added together.

Comment: What you want is just `total_sales = sum(month_sale)`. You don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems: the print in the input and the use of the sum: the argument of sum is an iterable (list, tuple, ...) but you provide items which is an integer.
Here is the code without these errors:

```
def sales_function():
    month_list = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
    month_sale = []
    for months in month_list :
        user_input = int(input("Enter the sales for " + months +":" ))
        month_sale.append(user_input)
    total_sales = sum(month_sale)
    print("Total sales:", total_sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tab indentation` is needed after defining the function you want to write, in order to tell python that the code after the definition is the code of the function.

Tip: you should call the lists you use with a plural name (for example: `month_list` becomes `months`) and be able to iterate using the corresponding singular and plural form (`for month in months:`).

You don't need to call the `print` function when you want to take a look at the content of a variable: just pass the name of the variable you want to see in a new line.

Also you don't really want to cast an `input` directly to Python type. For example if the user inputs a string "Sup" instead of a required integer, Python will throw an exception when you try to cast "Sup" to an integer. This causes the end of the execution of the program (if you don't handle the exception manually using a [`try except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) statement).

For the other `for` loop you don't need `range(len())`, just use `for month_sale in month_sales` to carry out the iteration.

After this, I'm going to guess that you wanted to print the sum of all the month sales. Here it is:

```py
def sales_function():
    months_list = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
    month_sales = []
    for month in months_list :
        user_input = int(input("Enter the sales for " + month +":" ))
        month_sales.append(user_input)
    
    total_sales = 0
    for month_sale in month_sales:
        total_sales = total_sales + month_sale
    print("Total sales:" + str(total_sales))
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution for you.

```
   def sales_function():
month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
              'November', 'December']
month_sale = []
for months in month_list:
    user_input = input("Enter the sales for " + months + ":")
    month_sale.append(user_input)
print("Total sales:", len(month_sale))
```